# gps location value dont print android

Tags: android, gps, textview

in this code i want to get the longitude and latitude and convert them to string 
to use it on the screen 
and sms 
so how can i deal with it 
should i do new class ? or this code is just modified

what should i do to make it work 
i used all permitions for locations

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener  {

    Location location; // location

    LocationManager locationManager;
    public String LatTxt;
    public String LonTxt;
    public Double latitude; // latitude
    public Double longitude; // longitude
    TextView latTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Latitude_Txt);
    TextView lonTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Longitude_Txt);
    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters
    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = (long) (1000 * 60 * 0.25); // 0.25
                                                                                // minute

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener locListener = new MyLocationListener();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,locListener);

        lonTextView.setText(" " + location.getLongitude());
        latTextView.setText(" " + location.getLatitude());

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        LatTxt = latitude.toString();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LonTxt = longitude.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}






<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Latitude_Txt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Latitude"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put

```
lonTextView.setText(" " + location.getLongitude());
latTextView.setText(" " + location.getLatitude());
```

to

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


}
```

You try to print `location` in: `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` but `location` doesn't initiated.

BTW, add before lines:

```
 lonTextView.setText(" " + location.getLongitude());
 latTextView.setText(" " + location.getLatitude());
```

this code, to init old location

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,this); 
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

and remove your `requestLocationUpdates`

**[EDIT]**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener  {

Location location; // location

LocationManager locationManager;
public String LatTxt;
public String LonTxt;
public Double latitude; // latitude
public Double longitude; // longitude
TextView latTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Latitude_Txt);
TextView lonTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Longitude_Txt);
// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters
// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = (long) (1000 * 60 * 0.25); // 0.25
                                                                            // minute

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener locListener = this;
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,locListener);



}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    LatTxt = latitude.toString();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    LonTxt = longitude.toString();

    lonTextView.setText(" " + location.getLongitude());
    latTextView.setText(" " + location.getLatitude());
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }
}
```

Comment: see my edit, i fixed your code, remove all from `onProviderEnabled`

Comment: i am so sorry 
it still crash

Comment: 09-12 14:34:52.690: W/ActivityThread(26906): Application com.example.vehicletrackmaster is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
09-12 14:34:52.700: I/System.out(26906): Sending WAIT chunk
09-12 14:34:52.715: I/dalvikvm(26906): Debugger is active
09-12 14:34:52.900: I/System.out(26906): Debugger has connected
09-12 14:34:52.905: I/System.out(26906): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-12 14:34:53.105: I/System.out(26906): waiting for debugger to settle...

Comment: 09-12 14:34:53.305: I/System.out(26906): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-12 14:34:53.510: I/System.out(26906): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-12 14:34:53.710: I/System.out(26906): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-12 14:34:53.910: I/System.out(26906): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-12 14:34:54.105: I/System.out(26906): debugger has settled (1323)
09-12 14:34:55.645: D/dalvikvm(26906): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)

Comment: log are in this txt file

Comment: see row 85, you have `findViewById` error. You try to load `findViewById(R.id.XXXXX` and get null instead, check it

Comment: TextView latTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Latitude_Txt);

Comment: add to your post `activity_main` XML

Comment: <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Latitude_Txt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Latitude"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

Comment: add it post not to this comment

Answer (score 0):

when a new GPS coordinate is received. The function onLocationChanged will be called. You should do your GPS coordinate manipulations in there